# Remove "Next privilege: participate in Meta" on profile on Meta.SE

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When you have less than 5 rep on Meta.SE, the Activity tab on a profile says "Next privilege: participate on Meta". However, this is not a real privilege on Meta.SE.

Can this privilege please be hidden on the Activity tab?

[image: Next privilege: Participate in Meta]

Comment: Maybe it should be [fixed at the source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

Comment: @Scimonster Good point. Forgot to look there.